# Converting cell array of matrices to a 2D matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a cell-array of matrices (`A`):

[image]

And want to convert this into a singular 2D matrix by padding each column to an equal length (in this case - 197) and reshaping it in a specific manner such A{1,1} occupies the first three columns of the output matrix, A{1,2} occupies the next three and so forth.

The latter can likely be achieved via `horzcat` however I am not sure how to pad a cell array when each cell contains a matrix - rather than a vector, where i'd normally use something along the lines of:

```
Lmax = max(max(cell2mat(cellfun(@numel,A,'un',0)))) ;
b = cellfun(@(c)[c(:);NaN(Lmax-numel(c),1)],A,'uniformoutput',0);
```

Padding with either NaNs or 0's is acceptable.

How can I do this?

Comment: are all your matrix inside the cell array with 3 columns exactly (only the number of line differ) ?

Comment: @Hoki Yes - always three columns, however the number of cells can be variable.

Comment: @m.s Updated, I incorrectly labelled it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an extension of the previous answer to your question [Pad cell array with whitespace and rearrange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32372737/pad-cell-array-with-whitespace-and-rearrange).

The method is exactly the same, the only trick now you have matrices instead of vectors is to use `size` instead of `numel`.
It becomes:

```
%// sample data
A = { randi(10,5,3) , randi(10,8,3) ; randi(10,6,3) , randi(10,3,3) } 
A = 
    [5x3 double]    [8x3 double]
    [6x3 double]    [3x3 double]
```

Using the same method (replacing `numel` with `size(...,1)` to get the number of lines right:

```
%%
nCol = 3 %// number of columns for the padding lines

%// get the length of the longest vector
Lmax = max(max( cellfun('size',A,1) )) ;
%// pad columns with necessary number of NaN
b = cellfun( @(c) [c ; NaN(Lmax-size(c,1),nCol)], A ,'un',0 ) ;
%// reshape if you want your cell array in columns
b = b(:).' 

>> b
b = 
    [8x3 double]    [8x3 double]    [8x3 double]    [8x3 double]
```

Answer (score 1):

*Almost* vectorized approach with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)'s masking capability -

```
%// Set parameters
nrows = cellfun('size',A,1)
ncols = size(A{1,1},2)
maxr = max(nrows)

%// Get mask
mask = bsxfun(@le,[1:maxr]',nrows)  %//'
out = zeros(maxr*numel(nrows),ncols)
out(mask(:),:) = vertcat(A{:})

%// Final output
b = reshape(permute(reshape(out,maxr,numel(nrows),[]),[1 3 2]),maxr,[])
```

Sample run -

```
>> A{1,1}
ans =
     5     6     2
     6     9     1
     4     7     1
     4     4     2
     5     8     3
>> A{1,2}
ans =
     3     5     2
     1     1     6
>> A{1,3}
ans =
     8     5     5
     9     5     1
     6     3     8
     9     4     1
>> A{1,4}
ans =
     4     8     4
>> b
b =
     5     6     2     3     5     2     8     5     5     4     8     4
     6     9     1     1     1     6     9     5     1     0     0     0
     4     7     1     0     0     0     6     3     8     0     0     0
     4     4     2     0     0     0     9     4     1     0     0     0
     5     8     3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: What makes this almost vectorised as opposed to fully vectorised?

Comment: @AnnaSchumann Use of `cellfun('size',A,1)` as `cellfun` isn't really a vectorized usage, but that should be very light on performance as it's not doing any computation with it. I was just trying to be technically correct there :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `numel` you need to use `size`, then the following modification of your code works:

```
Lmax = max(cellfun('size',A,1));
b = cellfun(@(c)[c;NaN(Lmax-size(c,1),3)],A,'uniformoutput',0);

c = horzcat(b{:}); % this holds your final matrix
```

Comment: `length` is very dangerous. In this case it should be all right but if you **know** you have to get the number of **lines**, use `size(A,1)` as they could be no indetermination this way.

Comment: Or use the in-built `cellfun('size',A,1)`, should be faster.

Comment: @Divakar, thanks ... changed it too, I didn't know we could use this syntax.